# Роутеры RegExp

Tags: framework, zend-framework

Используется фреймворк Zend framework (version 1.12.0)

Возникла проблема с правильным прописанием роутера

Путь может выглядеть так: www.site.com/v1/messages/get

Изначально v1 (или v2 и т.п. - это подкаталог для разных версий сайта) не было, и конфиг выглядел так:

```
routes.messages.route = '/messages/:action'
routes.messages.type = 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route'
routes.messages.defaults.module = 'default'
routes.messages.defaults.controller = 'messages'
routes.messages.defaults.action = 'index'
```

Т.е. он методы перенаправлял сам

Для версии я использовал такой конфиг (с учетом, что версии в пути может и не быть):

```
routes.messages.route = '(v/d+\/)?messages'
routes.messages.type = 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regexp'
routes.messages.defaults.module = 'default'
routes.messages.defaults.controller = 'messages'
routes.messages.defaults.action = 'index'
```

Проблема в том, что при Regexp нельзя напиcать так: "(v/d+\/)?/messages/:action"
А  "(v/d+\/)?/messages/(\w+)?" не обрабатывается как надо.
Кто может сказать, как надо правильно написать regexp, чтобы не писать дял каждого метода messages роутер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял как можно сделать.
Создаем роутер для версии:

```
routes.version.route = '(v\d+)?'
routes.version.type ='Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex'
```

А затем у каждого роутера (вне зависимочти от типа) создаем Chain:

```
routes.chain_auth.type = 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain'
routes.chain_auth.chain = 'version, auth'
```

В моем случае допустимо перед стандартными контроллерами указывать версию (vНомер), и не нужно для каждого метода писать свой роутер. Просто пишем chain после каждого  все.

Answer (score 0):

ну во первых, вы не правильно сам regex написали

```
routes.messages.route = '(v\d+\/)?messages'
```

Незнаю специфику вашей задачи, но не думаю что вам в параметрах надо "v<число>/", например "v12/". В таком случае лучше использовать такой regex:

```
routes.messages.route = 'v(\d+)\/?messages'
```

Во вторых, все таки прийдется для каждого экшна прописывать роуты.
Пример вот [здесь](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config)